# C# SharpDevelop DataGridView in Mainform.Designer.cs....want to access in MainForm.cs but is getting a "cross thread error"

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm using *C# SharpDevelop*. A `DataGridView` is created/initialized in Mainform *Designer.cs* and I want to access it (clear/add row) in *MainForm.cs* but is getting a "cross thread run time error" :

> accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on

Any simple ways around this?

Thanks.

Comment: This can be single threaded...no need for multiple threads

Comment: @user3063679 There are always multiple threads, events may be spawned on separate threads, etc. The problem is that you always have to do UI operations on the UI thread, and it isn't always clear what thread you are currently in, which is why you need the Invoke.

Comment: did more searching and this seems to only occur in the debugger...I ran the executable and it does not happen...

Comment: @user3063679 Microsoft intentionally designed it that way, so developers are warned when they debug the applications. It does not crash the program at runtime, which seems to be friendly to "end users", but can be a bad of accepting programming mistakes.